# Likelihood ratio test for mean - Laplace distributions

Tags: statistics, laplace-transform, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Let $W_1,\ldots, W_n$, $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ and $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ be independent samples. They have the laplace density:
$$f_W(x)=\frac{1}{2}\exp\lbrace -|x-\theta_1| \rbrace$$
$$f_Y(x)=\frac{1}{2}\exp\lbrace -|x-\theta_2| \rbrace$$
$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{2}\exp\lbrace -|x-\theta_3| \rbrace$$

Derive the approximative Power for the likelihood ratio test with $\alpha=0.05$ for $H_0: \theta_1=\theta_2=\theta_3$

I want to find the answer in terms of a non-central $\chi^2$ distribution, where I need to identify the degrees of freedome and the non centrality parameter.

So first of all I need to find the $2\log \lambda = 2(\ell(\hat{\theta})-\ell(\tilde{\theta}))$ then find the power of the test.
Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You need to start by saying what test statistic, what level of significance, and what critical value you are using. As I recall, the sample median, not mean, is the MLE for the center of a Laplace distribution.

Comment: Im using the likelihood ratio test: $2log\lambda$ with $\alpha=0.05$

Comment: $H_0: \theta_1=\theta_2=\theta_3$ if n=200. and $\theta_1=1.8$, $\theta_2 = 2.0$, and $\theta_3=2.2$

Comment: I need to identidy the approximate degrees of freedome of a chi2 distribution and reject $H_0$ if $2\log \lambda > c$ where $c$ is the 95th percentile of $\chi^2_{r-q}$